# Asking for user input, and then ignoring it

Tags: c++

I want to ask the user for input, and then just ignore than input. I don't care what the user puts, I just care that the user types something in (actually I don't really care if they do that, but I want to make them *think* that they have to type something in).

I get that I can do something like this:

```
std::cout << "Type something: ";
{
   int i;
   std::cin >> i;
}
std::cout << "You typed something.";
```

But I was wondering if there was some easy, *clean* one-line alternative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use 
[`cin.ignore`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/) or [`cin::get`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/).

e.g.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout << "press enter key.\n";
    std::cin.ignore();
}
```